# On hover visibility not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display div`.user-options` on hover on `.box1`. but when i mouseover the `.box1` the `.user-options` is not visible. what can be the cause?

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="user-settings.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="box">

<div class="box1"></div>

<div class="user-options">
<ul class="settings">
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">blah blah</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Customization</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
 .box1{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:orange;
}

.user-options{
    background:orange;
    visibility:hidden;
    width:200px;
}

.settings{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0px;
}

.box .box1:hover .user-options{
    visibility:visible;
}

.settings a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: `.user-options` is not a descendant of `.box1` so `.box .box1:hover .user-options` will not work

Comment: Do you need like this: http://jsfiddle.net/p2y1nLq2/1/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Quentin and wf4 mentioned, its not possible to use the way you tried..

so you can try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p2y1nLq2/1/)**

```
.box {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:orange;
}
.box > .user-options {
    background:orange;
    width:200px;
    display:none;   
   position: relative;
}
.settings {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0px;
}
.settings a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.box:hover > .user-options {
    display:block;
     position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
.box .box1:hover .user-options
                ^
                ^
```

That is a [*descendant* combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators). The user-options element is not a descendant of the box1 element, so the selector doesn't match.

They are siblings, use one of the [sibling combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#sibling-combinators) (such as [`+`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators)) instead.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
.box > .box1:hover + .user-options {...}
```